# Why is it a must to assign sysadmin role to the sql agent service account?

Tags: sql-server

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/select-an-account-for-the-sql-server-agent-service?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-role-membership

I am analyzing a production server in which the sql server agent service account is not assigned the sysadmin role. There are jobs scheduled and everything seems to be working fine.

Why is it a must to assign sysadmin role to the sql agent service account?

Here are other links where it mentions about sysadmin role:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-service-startup-account-sql-server-agent-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017#Restrictions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-service-startup-account-sql-server-agent-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017#Permissions

Comment: Probably only MS can answer this and possibly as simple answer as "This is what we have tested and this is what we support". I.e., if enough of us talk to MS and demand that this isn't acceptable, they might spend dev time to investigate whether this can be changed. Btw, I though that the very first thing that Agent does is to verify that it is sysadmin... I know it used to do this, but I couldn't find such a test in a trace when I start my Agent on 2019. So this is possibly something they started to work on...

Comment: Here are other links mentioning that sysadmin is a must: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-service-startup-account-sql-server-agent-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017#Restrictions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-service-startup-account-sql-server-agent-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017#Permissions